# Selecionar indice de uma array que esta dentro de outro array

Tags: array, groovy

Possuo um `ArrayList` que possui outros `ArrayList` dentro dele, consegui atráves do seguinte scrip em Groovy:

```
def i0 = listaTransportadoras.get([0]);
def i1 = listaTransportadoras.get(1);

logger.info(i0.toString());
logger.info(i1.toString());
```

Selecionar o 1º e 2º array que estão dentro desse array principal, porém preciso pegar os indices que estão dentro de cada um desses "subarrays", se tiverem um ideia agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui da seguinte forma acessar os dados dos subArrays:

```
List item = new ArrayList(); // Array que irá receber os registros de cada subArray

def x = 0;
def i = listaTransportadoras.size(); //Quantidade de colunas nos subArrays
logger.info("Quantidade: "+i.toString());

while (x <= (i - 1)){
    item = listaTransportadoras.get(x); 
    transportadoras.codigo.add(item.get(0));
    transportadoras.nome.add(item.get(1));
    logger.info("Codigo Registro: "+item.get(0).toString());
    logger.info("Nome Registro: "+item.get(1).toString());
    x++;
    item.clear();
}
```

Comment: Parece ser muito código só para fazer um loop. Também notei que você usa elementos nativos do Java mais que a maneira do Groovy. Fazer loop com Groovy é bem fácil. O uso de while e outros é menos desejável do que usar iteradores como o each: `lista.each { println it }`, onde lista é definida como `lista = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e'], ['f']]` e o resultado seria cada lista interna em sua própria linha: `[a, b]
[c, d, e]
[f]`

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi bem a pergunta, mas você pode acessar os elementos da ArrayList facilmente assim:

```
def lista = [['a', 'b'], ['d', 'e'], ['c']]

lista[0] // Primeiro elemento da lista: primeira ArrayList => [a, b]
lista[0][0] // Primeiro elemento da primeira ArrayList => a
lista[0][1] // Segundo elemento da primeira ArrayList => b

lista[0].size // Número de elementos na primeira ArrayList => 2
lista[2].size // Número de elementos na terceira (e última) ArrayList => 1
```

Comment: Postei uma resposta para mostrar como resolvi meu problema, mas obrigado pelo retorno